# JavaScript for Commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

The code below was created for us as a custom button in the UI on the Opportunity object.  I would like to now include it in a Visualforce page for a custom object as a Commandbutton.  I am not very familiar with JavaScript.  Can anyone help me convert this code to a script I can use in a VF page?  Thanks.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var CRL=''; 
var DST=''; 
var CES='';
//*************************************************// 
// Modify individual options here: 
// Related Content (default no related content) 
// Custom Recipient List 
CRL = 'Email~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Email__c)};
FirstName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_FirstName__c)};
LastName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_LastName__c)};
Role~Signer1,Email~test@test.com;FirstName~Test;LastName~Test1;
Role~Signer 2'; 
DST = '0E9AB63C-62C0-4D01-B91A-E58849B7B573'; 
CES='Insertion Order signature request for {!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Name_Rendered__c)}';
//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&STB=1&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&LA=0&CRL="+CRL+"&DST="+DST+"&CES="+CES; 
//*******************************************//
```

Comment: just use `<script>` tags?

Comment: Thanks @Novarg, but where do I need to put them and do I need to remove the {!REQUIRESCRIPT...} reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. Create a vf page with below code save the page with executeScript name

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.example_js}"/>
     <script>
     function executeScript()
     {

      var CRL=''; 
        var DST=''; 
        var CES='';

        CRL = 'Email~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Email__c)};
        FirstName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_FirstName__c)};
        LastName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_LastName__c)};
        Role~Signer1,Email~test@test.com;FirstName~Test;LastName~Test1;
        Role~Signer 2'; 
        DST = '0E9AB63C-62C0-4D01-B91A-E58849B7B573'; 
        CES='Insertion Order signature request for {!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Name_Rendered__c)}';
        //********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
        window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&STB=1&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&LA=0&CRL="+CRL+"&DST="+DST+"&CES="+CES;
        }
     </script>
     <input type="button" value="Execute script" onclick="executeScript();"/> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

New code

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
        <apex:form>
         <script>
         function executeScript()
         {

          var CRL=''; 
            var DST=''; 
            var CES='';

            CRL = 'Email~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Email__c)}';             
            DST = '0E9AB63C-62C0-4D01-B91A-E58849B7B573'; 
            CES='Insertion Order signature request for {!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Name_Rendered__c)}';
            window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&STB=1&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&LA=0&CRL="+CRL+"&DST="+DST+"&CES="+CES;
            }
         </script>
         <input type="button" value="Execute script" onclick="executeScript();"/> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Now open page executeScript and pass opportunity id like below example

**/apex/executeScript?Id=0061d55rf5th54g**

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but got an error that the $Resource.example_js was not found.

Comment: just remove <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.example_js}"/> this

Comment: Thanks.  I removed that and everything saves.  However, when I press the Commandbutton, all it does is refresh the page.  Do you know how I can debug the button to figure out why it's not invoking the script?

Comment: Thanks.  It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" but doesn't give any more info than that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know why it might be happening?  Is my window.location.href component formatted properly?  I did try hard coding the URL and it does work.  For some reason, it's not reading it properly in my script.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That comes back with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I forgot to add the semi-colon.  It still gives me the same original error and it looks like it points to the window.location.href line as the unexpected string.

Comment: No.  Now I'm getting a "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: @J.Neilan in your custom button same code is working? 404 error means server error looks like docusign server error

Comment: I added the button code to the UI interface and tried it there.  It does re-direct to the DocuSign page.  Any idea why the command button would return a 404 error?

Comment: Just to follow up it looks like there is an issue with a resource called "logo180.png" that is an SFDC resource.  It's a known issue designed to prevent malware, but I can't figure out how to block the image from being loaded.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I am stuck in very similar situation.

Comment: @abhi if you have a new question please ask a new question.